# Ordenar SQL por fecha strftime("%B/%Y")

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos, sql

Tengo el siguiente query:

```
    SELECT 
mes_de_pago AS dateGroup2, 
SUM(monto) AS 'monto_total2' 
FROM pagos 
WHERE status_pago = 'APROBADO' 
GROUP BY dateGroup2 
ORDER BY mes_de_pago DESC
```

El resultado que obtengo es este:

```
dateGroup2       monto_total2
octubre/2018      21
noviembre/2018    49
marzo/2019        39
febrero/2019      36
enero/2019        13
diciembre/2018    40
```

La estructura de la columna mes_de_pago es un vachar `mes_de_pago   varchar(30)` pero el contenido que se almacena alli es un mes seguido de un diagonaL y el año ese dato lo obtengo mediante php con el siguiente dato: `strftime("%B/%Y");` y la salida que esa linea php me brinda me permite guardarla en mi BD como se puede ver en la salida que muestro en mi ejemplo.

Quisiera saber si es posible darle las instrucciones a mi sentencia para que el orden de mi salida sea como el indicado a continuación:

```
marzo/2019
febrero/2019
enero/2019
diciembre/2018
noviembre/2018
octubre/2018
```

He agregado una columna con propiedades DATATIME que se llama `fecha_aprobacion` con la finalidad de que no sea una cadena vachar pero de verdad no se como hacer que funcione en el orden que requiero.

**Mi codigo completo es el siguiente:**

```
$sqlq = "SET lc_time_names = 'es_VE'";
$resultadoq = mysqli_query($db,$sqlq);


$sql_epe = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(fecha_pedido,'%M %Y') AS dateGroup, SUM(monto) AS 'monto_total' FROM pedidos WHERE status_pedido = 'ENTREGADO' GROUP BY dateGroup ORDER by DATE_FORMAT(dateGroup, '%m/%d') DESC LIMIT 0 , $limit_end";


$sql_apa="SELECT DATE_FORMAT(fecha_aprobacion,'%M %Y') AS dateGroup2, SUM(monto) AS 'monto_total2' FROM pagos WHERE status_pago = 'APROBADO' GROUP BY dateGroup2 ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(dateGroup2, '%m/%d') DESC LIMIT 0 , $limit_end";


    $result_apa = mysqli_query($db, $sql_apa);

    $datos_apa = array();

    // ahora guardamos los datos de la consulta apa en nuestro array
    while ($j = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_apa)) {
      array_push($datos_apa, $j['monto_total2']);
      }

      $i = 0;

  $resultado_estadistica .= "<h4>ESTADISTICA DE PEDIDOS ENTREGADOS</h4>";

  $resultado_estadistica .= '<table id="estadistica" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead>
  <tr>
  <th>Mes</th> 
  <th>Ventas Mensual</th>
  <th>Mensualidades </th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>';

  while ($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_epe)){

    $dateGroup = strtoupper($r['dateGroup']);
    $monto_total = $r['monto_total'];
    $monto_total2 = $datos_apa[$i];
    //$monto_total2 = $r['monto_total2'];
    $venta_mensual = number_format($monto_total, 2, ',', '.');
    $mensualidades = number_format($monto_total2, 2, ',', '.');

    $resultado_estadistica .= '<tr>';
    $resultado_estadistica .= '<td>'.$dateGroup.'</td>
                               <td>'.$venta_mensual .' Bs.'.'</td>
                               <td>'.$mensualidades .' Bs.'.'</td>';
     $resultado_estadistica .= ' </tr>';
     $i = $i + 1;
  }   

  $resultado_estadistica .= '</tbody></table>';
```

En esencia el funciona pero organiza los resultados de una manera extraña, puede presentar los datos en el siguiente orden:

```
enero febrero marzo
o lo puede hacer:
marzo, diciembre, noviembre
o lo hace:
febrero, marzo, enero, febrero
```

y me gustaria que el orden sea asi:

```
    marzo/2019
    febrero/2019
    enero/2019
    diciembre/2018
    noviembre/2018
    octubre/2018
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías crear una nueva consulta a partir de tu mes_de_pago para convertirlo a numero y alli ordenarlo, te dejo un ejemplo

```
SELECT * FROM pagos 
WHERE status_pago = 'APROBADO'  
substr(mes_de_pago) AS sortabledate
ORDER BY sortabledate ASC
```

perdona los errores, no soy tan bueno en sql , ojala te ayude.

Comment: Gracias por contestar pero esas lineas de codigo dan error de sintaxis